# How do I install Ubuntu on Samsung Chromebook 3?

Tags: chromebook, system-installation

So I followed the instructions that were posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254412/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-a-chromebook-3?rq=1).

Everything seems to be going as planned until I got to the Last step where I was supposed to "configure wifi, open the terminal and run the script again. It'll download a bunch of files then reboot into Ubuntu."

After running the script

```
wget http://cr-48-ubuntu.googlecode.com/files/arm-chrubuntu-3.sh
sudo bash arm-chrubuntu-3.sh
```

for a second time and waiting for all sorts of files to download, My chromebook never rebooted into Ubuntu.

I tried to open a terminal and typing `sudo cgpt add -i 6 -P 5 -S 1 /dev/mmcblk0` and nothing happened, just another empty command line.

And I just now set my chromebook back to its normal settings, then switched it back to developer mode and retyped

```
wget http://cr-48-ubuntu.googlecode.com/files/arm-chrubuntu-3.sh
sudo bash arm-chrubuntu-3.sh
```

and it asked me how many gigs I wanted to reserve for Ubuntu 5-1 and recommending 0 as the maximum when I choose the number zero (0) it said error please choose a number, then I typed the letter O and it rebooted my Chromebook and repaired the OS. After it repaired the OS it brought me back to me login for chrome os and I just set up the network connection and opened a terminal logged in as chronos and  redid the whole process again and this time it started to download all these files and still after all the downloads my Chromebook didn't reboot into Ubuntu. What Should I do?